# Nested application ignores bundles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, t4mvc, asp.net-bundling

I'm trying to run my ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3.0 application as nested application so that I can access it as a subfolder, like http://example.com/my-application.
I've added it to an existing application by choosing Add Application a chosen separate application pool.
When I run my-application on its own URL it works fine however when I try to run it as http://example.com/my-application it refuses to render bundles, neither style nor js.
What I have tried so far:

- I have tried to enable and disable bundling and minification. When it's disabled Styles.Render adds nothing to markup. When it's enabled invalid link to bundle is added to markup, for example `<link href="/calc/bundles/styles/mainlayout?v=" rel="stylesheet"/>` and the link returns empty document.
- I have tried to put my-application to empty website to ensure no side effects inherited. No difference here.
- I have tried to put brand new application side by side with my-application and bundling worked fine there so it must be something wrong with my application and I can not find what exactly.
- I have tried to ILSpy System.Web.Optimization code but couldn't find any help there.
- I have failed to debug System.Web.Optimization as my VS just hung.
- I didn't find any conflicting routes with my-application address.

If anyone faced the same issue then any advice appreciated.
Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I found what causes the issue. We intensively use T4MVC and we use it for bundles configuration as well. So our bundle declaration looks something like:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts")
       .Include("~" + Links.Scripts.Script1_js, "~" + Links.Scripts.Script2_js));
```

And `"~" + Links.Scripts.Script1_js` for nested application gives me `~/my-application/scripts/script1.js` while `VirtualPathProvider` from inside `Include` method expects it to be `~/scripts/script1.js`.

So the question transforms into: does anyone know how to prevent T4MVC from adding nested application path onto static files links so that application isn't aware of being nested? I bet @David Ebbo knows how to achieve this :)